# How to optimize this query in Oracle 12.1.0.2?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Consider this SQL statement:

```
select *
  from chamado.servico se
  join chamado.chamado ch on ch.id_servico=se.id_servico
  join chamado.statuschamado sc on sc.id_statuschamado=ch.id_statuschamado
 where sc.id_statuschamado=1
;
```

Now consider the corresponding execution plan:

[image]

Now Pay close attention ibn the red box! The filter predicate (`CH.ID_STATUSCHAMADO=1`). It is not in the query and it is the most expensive operation.

The table `SERVICO` has less than 200 rows, the table `STATUSCHAMADO` has less than 10 rows, but the table `CHAMADO` has more than 70000 rows.

My intention with those joins where to have full table scan only on STATUSCHAMADO and SERVICO, what was supposed to impose a lite overhead on Oracle.

What is wrong in my statement?

## Update 1

I have the following indices:

1. CHAMADO.ID_CHAMADO (PK)
2. CHAMADO.ID_SERVICO
3. CHAMADO.ID_AREAATENDIMENTO
4. SERVICO.ID_SERVICO (PK)
5. AREAATENDIMENTO.ID_AREAATENDIMENTO (PK)

Comment: Please tell us which indices you already have created on these tables.  Note that `SELECT *` is generally not an index friendly thing.  If you don't really need all columns, then just list out the columns you really do need.

Comment: This query needs atleast use indexes on `chamado.servico(id_servico)` `chamado.chamado(id_servico, id_statuschamado)` and `chamado.statuschamado(id_statuschamado)` to remove the nested loops need, unless the Oracle optimizer chose to do nested loops  as (part off) the acces plan for a reason..

Comment: *"The filter predicate (CH.ID_STATUSCHAMADO=1). It is not in the query and it is the most expensive operation."*  is most likely a column with a low number of possible unique values right? If that is the case using a partition per value might be a beter option.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: I created the index as you suggested and the overall cost indeed droped to 50%, so it's an improvement! Regarding `CH.ID_STATUSCHAMADO=1`, yes that column provides low selectivity in `CHAMADO`, that´s why I added a join to the `STATUSCHAMADO` expecting a full table scan there.

Comment: *"yes that column provides low selectivity in CHAMADO, that´s why I added a join to the STATUSCHAMADO expecting a full table scan there. "* Maybe you can force the optimizer into doing that with a delivered table ...  `INNER JOIN (SELECT ... ) alias` approach if you catch mine point here..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Ok, I will try. However, your tip on the new index was good enough to me. Post it as an answer and I will take it.

Comment: Although in this example the "cost" value has alerted you to something interesting, it isn't generally a useful metric in performance tuning. If you change the query and the calculated cost is lower, that doesn't generally mean very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The filter predicate (CH.ID_STATUSCHAMADO=1)...is not in the query" - perhaps not directly, but that's what's really happening. You're joining `STATUSCHAMADO sc` to `CHAMADO ch` on `sc.ID_STATUSCHAMADO = ch.ID_STATUSCHAMADO`, then in your `WHERE` clause you have `sc.ID_STATUSCHAMADO = 1`.

The database is smart enough to figure out that `sc.ID_STATUSCHAMADO` will always be 1, and therefore can substitute `CHAMADO.ID_STATUSCHAMADO = 1`. You also might try reversing the fields on the new index on STATUSCHAMADO - try it as `(ID_STATUSCHAMADO, ID_SERVICO)` as well as `(ID_SERVICO, ID_STATUSCHAMADO)`.